# I always get error for the MessageBlock.Text .The error says "The name Message block does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a windows phone application and i have to use NFC but while copying the proximity API from the web .I always get the error above

```
private Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher messageDispatcher = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher

async private void WriteMessageText(string message, bool overwrite = false)
{
   await messageDispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
   () =>
   {
          if (overwrite)
              MessageBlock.Text = message;
          else
              MessageBlock.Text += message;
  });
}
```

Comment: Where is `MessageBlock` declared?

Comment: I brought it from here while writing the readabily of nfc - http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice.devicearrived.aspx